# Make an atom preloader with 5 electrons using html js and css

Tags: html, css

I wanted a preloader in the form of an atom for my website and came across the following code:
https://codepen.io/Golmote/pen/icDuf
But I wanted an atom with 5 electrons (boron) and am struggling to edit the code to do so by adding new electrons and editing them corresponding to the other electrons:

```
@keyframes electron-circle1 {
    from { transform: rotateY(70deg) rotateZ(20deg); }
    to { transform: rotateY(70deg) rotateZ(380deg); }
 }
@keyframes electron1 {
     from { transform: rotateZ(-20deg) rotateY(-70deg); }
     to { transform: rotateZ(-380deg) rotateY(-70deg); }
}
.atom .electron:nth-child(1):before {
     transform: rotateZ(-20deg) rotateY(-70deg);
    animation: electron1 3s linear infinite;
}
```

It would be really helpful if someone from the community can help me in doing so.(changing the degree values )
Thank you.

Comment: you need to add/copy those 2 atoms and scale down (or up ) https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/MWgPeOW

Comment: @G-Cyr How do I tilt the electrons so that they become equidistant and equiangular from the other shells in your pen

Comment: for the tilt, it is about the rotate values , 3 makes each rotate around 60deg (180/3) , 5 should be 36deg, (180/5) 180deg, not 360 because they do not overlap but show on the other side ;)

Comment: @G-Cyr scale is just resizing the ring in terms of radius and not making it tilt more or less. typing 3 in the following section                                :     keyframes electron-circle4 {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(60deg) rotateX(60deg) rotateZ(-30deg) scale(3);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(60deg) rotateX(60deg) rotateZ(330deg) scale(3);
  }
} does not change the tilt but only the radius and size.

Comment: maybe you've been too much on it, take a step back ;) https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/MWgPjrm